# ionic 2 + angular 2 - tabs + side menu

Tags: angularjs, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic-view, ionic2

I'm trying to join tabs and side menu together, I'm confused on what I'm doing wrong. since root belongs to sidemenu..

```
import {App, IonicApp, Platform} from 'ionic-framework/ionic';

import {HelloIonicPage} from './pages/hello-ionic/hello-ionic';
import {ListPage} from './pages/list/list';
import {TabsPage} from './pages/tabs/tabs';


// https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/Type-interface.html
import {Type} from 'angular2/core';


@App({
  templateUrl: 'build/app.html',
  config: {} // http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/config/Config/
})
class MyApp {
  // make HelloIonicPage the root (or first) page
  rootPage: Type = HelloIonicPage;
  pages: Array<{title: string, component: Type}>;

  constructor(private app: IonicApp, private platform: Platform) {

    this.initializeApp();

    // set our app's pages
    this.pages = [
      { title: 'Hello Ionic', component: HelloIonicPage },
      { title: 'My First List', component: ListPage },
      { title: 'testing tabs', component: TabsPage}
    ];
  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      // The platform is now ready. Note: if this callback fails to fire, follow
      // the Troubleshooting guide for a number of possible solutions:
      //
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      //
      // First, let's hide the keyboard accessory bar (only works natively) since
      // that's a better default:
      //
      // Keyboard.setAccessoryBarVisible(false);
      //
      // For example, we might change the StatusBar color. This one below is
      // good for dark backgrounds and light text:
      // StatusBar.setStyle(StatusBar.LIGHT_CONTENT)
    });
  }

  openPage(page) {
    // close the menu when clicking a link from the menu
    this.app.getComponent('leftMenu').close();
    // navigate to the new page if it is not the current page
    let nav = this.app.getComponent('nav');
    nav.setRoot(page.component);
  }
}
```

I'm new to ionic and I have follow following tutorial http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/getting-started/tutorial/

It has tabs or side-menu, but does not have both. I have imported tabs, but I'm not sure what to do next, because `rootPage` belongs to `HelloIonicPage`, which I dont want to change.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is not totally clear why you would need to do this but it is possible and the attached link has the code where I merged the two programs generated by the templates. The resulting program uses the tab1 page as the 'Getting Started' page. Menu for the sidebar is available from each of the tab pages.

1. I copied the folders in the pages folder of the 'tabs' program to the 'sidemenu' program.
2. From the 'Getting Started' I copied the nav bar code and the menu for the side bar. This seems to be inherited by the tab 2 and tab 3 pages including the specified title (not sure of the reason). So I added a h1 with a tab2 and tab3 title in each of the pages just as markers.
3. I modified the app.ts file to import the pages added in step 1.
4. I added import statements to import page1, page2 and page3 html files in the app.core.scss

The approach may allow to add a login screen and other utility screens (such as search) on the sidebar.

[Merged Sidemenu and Tabs code in ionic 2](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/zwkvrf4pdq5jdpv/AAAdp24izuTJwJge2u7ezQBla?dl=0)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, We are building Quran app, so we wanted to show sidebar and tabs, but keep tabs as gesture show only (which we want to add later on).. that was the reason, I have downloaded the app and will try and hopefully everything will go well.

Comment: it works fine on ios, but does not show sidebar on andriod.

Comment: Also I have one question in this. what If I didn't wanted to use `rootPage: Type = TabsPage;`, but still want to show tab on existing page. how can I achive that? because I want to show tab on second page and not the home page.

Comment: Basit - I have not checked this on android. Regarding the side menu on a specific page move the following code from tabs.html to the specific page. Then the menu bar will be shown only on that page. But return by pressing the selection will always take you back to the first page. I am sure it is possible to fix the code to return to whatever you want. <ion-navbar *navbar>
  <button menuToggle>
    <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
  </button>
  <ion-title>Tab 2</ion-title>
</ion-navbar>

Comment: Basit - I tried using 'ionic serve -l' which shows both android and ios side-by-side. It seems to work fine on both.. I dont have a android device to check on.

Comment: I was checking on ionic lab, which also shows on side by side.

Comment: @Basit added example below that works allround. See screenshot

Comment: answer is old and out of date